# Propety 'children' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>' React Typescript

Tags: javascript, react, typescript

Estou tendo problemas ao declarar `{this.props.children}`, por algum motivo está dando erro quando tento declarar em uma `class React.Component`.

```
import style from "./square.module.scss";
import React from "react";

class Square extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <button className={style.square} onClick={() => console.log('Foi Clicado')}>
        {this.props.children}
      </button>);
  }
}

export default Square;
```

o Erro Apresentado é

> [{    "owner": "typescript",  "code": "2339",     "message": "Property
> 'children' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'.",   "source": "ts",

Comment: eu costumo usar react com functional components.. ficaria +- assim

`
interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
}
function Square ({children}: Props) {
    return (
      <button className={style.square} onClick={() => console.log('Foi Clicado')}>
        {children}
      </button>);
}`

Answer (score 1):

Precisa declarar o tipo na `props` da seguinte forma:

```
interface IProps {
 children: React.ReactChild;
}
```

e na classe declarar assim:

```
class Square extends React.Component<IProps> {
```

para demonstrar o tipo especifico. Nesse `props` pode contar outras propriedades e seus respectivos tipos, em especifico só foi declarado `children` que é do tipo [React.ReactChild](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-react-children-prop-typescript/)

Existe também a declaração geral com `any`, particularmente não é a melhor abordagem porque não traz as vantagens de utilizar os tipos fortes.

Answer (score 0):

React.ReactNode deve ser usado ao invés de React.ReactChild que foi descontinuado.

O componente deve ter o seguinte esqueleto em TypeScript:

```js
import React from "react";

interface IProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

interface IState {}

export default class Scroll extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  render() {
    return this.props.children;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alguma versão do react passou a não inferir mais esse tipo sozinho. Duas soluções: `class Square extends React.Component<{children?: ReactNode}>` ou `class Square extends React.Component<React.PropsWithChildren>`. Se tiver mais props pode só incluir no objeto literal no primeiro formato, ou no segundo fazer tipo `<React.PropsWithChildren<{minhaProp: string/*, ...*/}>>`